# ¿puedo usar npm in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Quisiera usar [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron) en angularjs, necesito ejecutar request dentro de un cron-job desde el controlador, ¿alguna idea? hasta ahora no he encontrado nada, excepto node-cron que es exactamente lo que necesito, saludos.

Comment: puedes colocar que has intentado con un poco de código...

Comment: pero, podría poner el código que sale en node-cron pero de que vale si no se puede hacer, sería bueno saber de alguna librería que me ayude.  :C